# tabs / fragments and memory leak

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I am working on an app (not written by me) which has an activity comprised of three tabs, each of which corresponds to its own fragment (I've never used fragments before). Each tab/fragment displays data structures that consume a lot of memory. I want to be confident that when I switch from one tab to another that the memory consumed by the outgoing tab/fragment is fully released. before the next one starts up.

So say for example there was a bitmap being displayed by the outgoing fragment - would it be essential to do a bitmap.release() first to ensure that the fragment released all of its memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listen for tab change event on your tab controller.

```
tabLayout.setOnTabChangedListener(<listener>);
```

on the callback method of your listener `(onTabChanged(int index, boolean isUserInput))`, get the previous fragment, call unbind drawables on its view in a recursive way (u need to write it). After doing it, you can also call `System.gc()` to give a hint to Dalvik VM to run garbage collector (just a hint, no guarantees).

sample code for unbinding:

```
public static void unbindDrawables(@Nullable View view) {
    if (view == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (view.getBackground() != null) {
        view.getBackground().setCallback(null);
    }

    if (view instanceof ImageView && ((ImageView) view).getDrawable() != null) {
        ((ImageView) view).getDrawable().setCallback(null);
    }

    if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
        if (view instanceof AbsListView) {
            // Clean out list view
            List<View> cells = Lists.newLinkedList();
            ((AbsListView) view).reclaimViews(cells);
            if (cells != null) {
                for (View c : cells) {
                    unbindDrawables(c);
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
                unbindDrawables(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```